# Why Android Studio can't resolve "import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;"?

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-api

I'm quite new in programming Android apps and I was following a tutorial to implement GPS location. But Android Studio can't resolve this import:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
```

I have written this code at the beginning:

```
package example.prova.it.prova5;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, LocationListener {

    private static final int REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR = 0;
    private static final String DIALOG_ERROR = null;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private boolean resolvingError;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
```

And I have imported this dependency in Gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
```

What's the problem? 
Thanks in advance (and sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 8):

You need to add the `Location` dependency in your Gradle file:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) you can find all the individuals APIs from Google Play Services.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

update Google Repository and Google Play Service in sdk manger to latest version